# How to uninstall motioneye on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have installed MotionEye on my Raspberry Pi, but I can't find any tutorials on how I would go about uninstalling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, it is as simple as doing

`sudo pip uninstall motioneye`